# Python: Why cmath.exp(1j*math.pi) gives the answer -1+1.2246063538223773e-16j but not simply -1

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers

So I tried to check [Euler's İdentity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) in python console:

```
import math
import cmath
cmath.exp(1j*math.pi)
```

and result was:

```
-1+1.2246063538223773e-16j
```

Shouldn't it be just -1.

Comment: Floating point math is imprecise.

Comment: Within the precision of the other values in your expressions, that *is* -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you were doing this calculation but you started with only 5 digits of pi and then at every stage you rounded to 5 significant figures. Do you think you'd get an exact answer? No, of course not, the tiny errors at each stage would produce an error in the answer.

Floating point maths is the same, except that this time you're working in binary instead of decimal.

Answer (score 5):

That's close enough for me -- Especially since `math.pi` isn't infinitely precise -- considering that, it would actually be the wrong answer if it gave you `-1+0j`.